# Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord "has_many :through" uniqueness validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Currently I insert a new relationship by everytime checking, if it doesn't exist:

```
unless Relationship.exists?(:entry_id => entry.id, :tag_id => tag.id)
```

How could I implement such validation inside the Relationship model, so that it wouldn't allow to have more than one relationship between the same entry and tag?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :entry
  belongs_to :tag
  validates :tag_id, :uniqueness => { :scope => :entry_id }
end
```

Answer (score 10):

Assuming your models look something like this:

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :relationships
  has_many :tags, :through => :relationships
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :relationships
  has_many :entries, :through => :relationships
end

class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :entry
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

You could add a unique validation to your `Relationship` join model:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :tag_id, :scope => :entry_id
```

The [`validates_uniqueness_of`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of) method will ensure that the Relationship doesn't already exist, and the `:scope` option will scope the match to the given column. The SQL generated by rails via this validation will look like:

```
SELECT `relationships`.id
FROM `relationships`
WHERE (`relationships`.`tag_id` = <tag id> AND `relationships`.`entry_id` = <entry id>)
LIMIT 1
```

(which you'll notice is essentially the same SQL generated by your explicit use of `Relationship.exists?(:entry_id => entry.id, :tag_id => tag.id)`), and if a record is found, validation will fail.

As well, as with any case where you want to validate uniqueness, ensure that you have a unique key on `tag_id, entry_id` in your `relationships` table. See [this article](http://railswarts.blogspot.com/2007/11/validatesuniquenessof-is-broken-and.html) and the "Concurrency and integrity" of the API page I linked above for more info.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I add the unique keys, that I would still be allowed to have the same tag_id for other entries, and many different tags for the same entry? add_index "relationships", ["tag_id"], :unique => true - I guess would block me from using same same tag_id more than once.

Comment: You have to create the index for *both* columns. In a migration it'd look like `add_index :relationships, [:tag_id, :entry_id], :unique => true`. Then, do your DBMS, a new row is only in conflict if the values of both columns match an existing row.

Comment: (that was supposed to be *to* your DBMS)