# How to make child model's field unique inside grandparent model's scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Long story short, I have models relationships defined like this:

Project `has_many :groups` 
Group   `has_many :items`

My goal is to make item names unique inside the project scope. Since `:items`
table does not have `project_id` foreign key defined, simply writing 
 `add_index :items, :name, unique: { scope: :project_id }` will not work. I'm new to rails, am i missing something? How can this problem be solved?

Comment: You can only scope on the columns in that table, so unless you add project_id to items, this can't be done in the DB. It can however be done via validation.

Comment: What is the best practice of solving such issues? Won't adding `project_id` to the `items` table result in a field duplication? Since the `project_id` can already be accessed through `item.group.project_id`.

Comment: The best case would be to do this via validations. `validates :name,  :uniqueness => {scope: :project}`

Comment: Unfortunately `Unknown column 'test_cases.project'` error is shown when trying to solve the issue via validations

Comment: My apologies, you will need to add `belongs_to :group` and `belongs_to :project, through: :group` to Items

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work either - `Unknown key: :through` is given when trying to use `belongs_to :project, through: :group` in `Item` model. It is mentioned in the best answer of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021322/belongs-to-through-associations) that the `belongs_to` association can't have a `through:` option.

Comment: @AlexanderLomia instead of `belongs_to :project, through: :group`, try `has_one :project, through: :group`.

Comment: Once you've set up your relationship correctly, a scope should work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129702/ruby-on-rails-activerecord-has-many-through-uniqueness-validation

Comment: Thanks guys, but i think that there might be a better way to solve this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best solution is to include `project_id` into `items` table and make (`project_id`, `item_name`) an unique index. To fill `project_id` column automatically, you can use `before_save` callback:

```
class Item
  before_save :fill_project_id_field

  private
  def fill_project_id_field
    self.project_id = self.group.project_id
  end
end
```

You can of course use validations, but it will not work well. As well as triggers (database side). They both assume you are the only one who works with database in the given moment. It's not always true, and you will end-up with data integrity problems, following this way.

Comment: Do you mean `add_index :items, :name, unique { scope: project_id }` by saying to make (`project_id`, `item_name`) a unique index?

Comment: I mean `add_index(:items, [:project_id, :item_name], unique: true)`. I've never seen `add_index` with `scope` before. Is it working too?

Comment: Seems like I've confused syntax with validations, thanks for pointing that out